# XSS_clean don't function with codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation, xss

I'm using codeigniter and i'm trying to do a form_validation but the XSS_CLean doesn't work, don't know why, i have in config.php $config['global_xss_filtering'] = TRUE;

Controller.php

```
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'required|trim|min_length[4]|max_length[12]|xss_clean');
```

required, min_length and more functions perfect but xss_clean no... i try to pass '"<> and it pass, what im doing bad ?

pd: sorry for my english!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<>` is not an XSS attempt.  The script removes potential XSS attacks.  The function allows harmless tags such as `<b>, <p>`.

[You can read the code itself.](https://github.com/EllisLab/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/core/Security.php#L272)  You will probably learn a lot about it.

If you want to encode all HTML entities, you can use the [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php) function form PHP.